# host.exp.exponent.MainApplication: java.lang.RuntimeException: NativeModuleDepsProvider could not find object for class class host.exp.exponent.p

Tags: android, react-native, expo

This is Expo detach project. It works properly debug mode but release mode crash contionusly.

And logcat logs

AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application host.exp.exponent.MainApplication: java.lang.RuntimeException: NativeModuleDepsProvider could not find object for class class host.exp.exponent.p

04-06 23:14:21.635  7295  7295 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-06 23:14:21.635  7295  7295 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.x.x, PID: 7295
04-06 23:14:21.635  7295  7295 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application host.exp.exponent.MainApplication: java.lang.RuntimeException: NativeModuleDepsProvider could not find object for class class host.exp.exponent.p
04-06 23:14:21.635  7295  7295 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5879)
04-06 23:14:21.635  7295  7295 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap3(ActivityThread.java)
04-06 23:14:21.635  7295  7295 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1699)
04-06 23:14:21.635  7295  7295 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-06 23:14:21.635  7295  7295 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
04-06 23:14:21.635  7295  7295 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
04-06 23:14:21.635  7295  7295 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
04-06 23:14:21.635  7295  7295 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
04-06 23:14:21.635  7295  7295 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
04-06 23:14:21.635  7295  7295 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: NativeModuleDepsProvider could not find object for class class host.exp.exponent.p
04-06 23:14:21.635  7295  7295 E AndroidRuntime:    at host.exp.exponent.c.a.b(NativeModuleDepsProvider.java:1108)
04-06 23:14:21.635  7295  7295 E AndroidRuntime:    at host.exp.a.b.(Exponent.java:136)
04-06 23:14:21.635  7295  7295 E AndroidRuntime:    at host.exp.a.b.a(Exponent.java:117)
04-06 23:14:21.635  7295  7295 E AndroidRuntime:    at host.exp.exponent.l.onCreate(ExpoApplication.java:75)
04-06 23:14:21.635  7295  7295 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1032)
04-06 23:14:21.635  7295  7295 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5876)
04-06 23:14:21.635  7295  7295 E AndroidRuntime:    ... 8 more

Comment: android/app/build.gradle

buildTypes {
    debug {
      debuggable true
      ext.enableCrashlytics = false
    }
    release {
      minifyEnabled true
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
      zipAlignEnabled true
    }
  }

under release replece with 
 release {
      debuggable false
    }
./apktool d zinder.apk  && ./apktool b zinder -o x.apk && jarsigner -verbose -tsa http://timestamp.digicert.com -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore zinderlastfriday last_zinder.apk zinder && ./zipalign -f -v 4 x.apk xa.apk

Comment: I also got this issue. I change to release { debuggable false } and it is still not okay. How shall I do?

Comment: What is the your errros. can you share with me ? you can paste it trace code 
https://paste.ubuntu.com/ thank you so much

Comment: @KhantThuLinn can you read my abone comment. did you clean cache? or 
you can execute below debug command when you connected your device. or virtual device.

adb -s logcat yourpackagename:V AndroidRuntime:E "*:S"

Comment: Somehow, it solve my issue now. I have asked Expo developer here 
https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/6188

Comment: I don't clean cache